# Remove index from dataframe using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a Pandas Dataframe from a string using the following code -

```
import pandas as pd

input_string="""A;B;C
0;34;88
2;45;200
3;47;65
4;32;140
"""

data = input_string
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in data.split('\n')])
print(df)
```

I am getting the following result -

```
    0     1     2
 0  A     B     C
 1  0    34    88
 2  2    45   200
 3  3    47    65
 4  4    32   140
 5     None  None
```

But I need something like the following -

```
 A     B     C
 0    34    88
 2    45   200
 3    47    65
 4    32   140
```

I added "index = False" while creating the dataframe like -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in data.split('\n')],index = False)
```

But, it gives me an error -

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, False 
was passed
```

How is this achievable?

Comment: So you wanted to read the column names from a header row, and also to set 'A' as the index. (And to not read an empty ghost row 5.) You can do all this with `pd.read_csv()` and wrap your input as a `io.StringIO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

input_string="""A;B;C 
0;34;88
2;45;200
3;47;65
4;32;140
"""

data = input_string
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in data.split()])
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df.set_index('A',inplace = True)
df
```

#### output

```
    B   C
A       
0   34  88
2   45  200
3   47  65
4   32  140
```

Comment: Any way to remove the first column as well? Like I mentioned in the question.
Column 'A' is the index for me

Comment: df.set_index('A')

Comment: I have updated the answer . I hope it works for you now.

Comment: @TeeKay  can you mark the answer if it was useful for you. Let me know if it worked?

Comment: Yes, this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `StringIO` and `index_col` parameetr for set first column to `index`:

```
input_string="""A;B;C
0;34;88
2;45;200
3;47;65
4;32;140
"""

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(input_string),sep=';', index_col=0)
print (df)
    B    C
A         
0  34   88
2  45  200
3  47   65
4  32  140
```

Your solution should be changed with split by default parameter (arbitrary whitespace), pass to DataFrame all  values of lists without first with columns parameter and if need first column to index add [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
L = [x.split(';') for x in input_string.split()]
df = pd.DataFrame(L[1:], columns=L[0]).set_index('A')
print (df)
    B    C
A         
0  34   88
2  45  200
3  47   65
4  32  140
```

For general solution use first value of first list in `set_index`:

```
L = [x.split(';') for x in input_string.split()]
df = pd.DataFrame(L[1:], columns=L[0]).set_index(L[0][0])
```

EDIT:

You can set column name instead index name to `A` value:

```
df = df.rename_axis(df.index.name, axis=1).rename_axis(None)
print (df)
A   B    C
0  34   88
2  45  200
3  47   65
4  32  140
```

Comment: 'B' and 'C' columns are there in the first row. 'A' comes in the second row. I want all three in one row.

Comment: @TeeKay - It is possible, but a bit hack. Check eited answer.